# which one past tense is correct?

Tags: past-tense

The significance of this research **was expected that can** help to improve the students’ reading comprehension.

or

The significance of this research **was expected that could** help to improve the students’ reading comprehension.

Comment: Would you explain a bit more what this sentence is supposed to express?

Comment: I find it difficult to understand the example sentences as written - "...expected that [verb] ..." isn't standard, and is confusing me. Could you describe a bit more what you're trying to express?

Answer (score 1):

Neither one is correct: "was expected that can" isn't grammatical and doesn't clearly express whatever you're trying to say, while "was expected that could" is technically grammatical but illogical. It seems to mean that there was an expectation (of significance) that was (the expectation itself, not the result) capable of helping reading comprehension. This is unlikely, to say the least.

Based on context, it sounds like what you mean is something like this:

> The significance of this research was that it was expected to help improve the students’ reading comprehension.

In this case, there was in the past an expectation of a particular outcome from research, which made that research significant.

Or you could shorten it further, as "significance" can be implied, and just say

> This research was expected to help improve the students’ reading comprehension.